# How to adjust all, absolutely all line widths in graphics made with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, width, line

I'm trying to standardize the aesthetics of my graphics with `ggplot2`. I used the `theme_set()` function for this. However, when looking closely at the graphics, not all lines have the desired width. In the following MWE, it is observed that the boxes and the horizontal line do not meet the standardization. This situation is also repeated with the lines of `geom_smooth()`. How can I solve this?

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(
  theme_bw() +
    theme(text = element_text(size = 8),
          line = element_line(colour = 1, size = 0.12),
          rect = element_rect(colour = 1, size = 0.12))
)

ggplot(data = ToothGrowth) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = supp, y = len)) +
  facet_grid(~dose) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 20,
             color = "red")
```

[image]

Zooming..

[image]

Comment: First sentence in`?theme`: Themes are a powerful way to customize the **non-data** components of your plots

Comment: @Henrik Got it. Do you know any way to customize data components?

Answer (score 2):

Add these before the `ggplot` call:

```
update_geom_defaults("boxplot", list(size = 0.12))
update_geom_defaults("hline", list(size = 0.12))
```

[image]